# Movie title: sounds like "Outlaw", mining industry on planet and drug problems

Tags: story-identification

I've searched but I've not until now been able to find the title of a movie I saw in the 80's. The title sounds like "Outlaw" or "Out-something". It was a story that occurs in a base on a planet, a mining industry. There were drug problems... I remember that (in the intro), on of the effect of this (bad) drug leads an astronaut to open his suit (with lethal consequence) because he believed it was full of insects or something like take.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It's [Outland](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outland_%28film%29) staring [Sean Connery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sean_Connery).

[image: Movie poster]

The mining takes place on Jupiter's moon of [IO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Io_%28moon%29). However (spoilers):

> the workers use drugs to help them work for days at a time. The drugs cause people to suffer from delirium tremens which makes them go outside without their suits, so that they die of decompression.

Comment: Sounds right to me.

Comment: Sean Connery ! Wow, I wouldn't ever recall that! This must have been the first time that I saw him in a movie. I've never made a link between this character and him...

Comment: @Rabskatran: that's how I found it. I read the description and thought, I think I've seen this with Sean Connery. Then it was off to Wikipedia, scan the film list and answer. :)

Comment: It was also a tribute to the classic western "High Noon", using some of the same plot points and situations.

Comment: @wikis : To be totally honest, I must confess that I've searched the filmography of Tom Selleck. That's how memory works, I guess :-P

Comment: I was an awesome movie.  Totally forgotten about it.  Now I need to go watch it again.

Comment: Ahhh, the classic "people explode violently in space" movie. I'm sure this movie contributed significantly to that [long-lived and incorrect trope](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ExplosiveDecompression), but it made for some fun scenes. ;)

Comment: @gnovice : Thanks for that link. I love it!