# Looking for a movie about a civilization that has to take a drug to withstand radiation

Tags: story-identification, movie

I vaguely remember a movie about a civilization that has to take a drug to withstand radiation. I think it was located in space. Probably the movie is from the late 70s or 80s. Any idea?

Comment: Im also looking for this film, have been for many years. The cigs were red and i think it was a team of space commandos on mars. I remember they had alerts reminding them to smoke their reds.

Comment: did you find this out? I remember the cigs being called "reds" too.

Comment: If reds and alerts, then it is Screamers, as in answers below.

Answer (score 4):

I was thinking "Screamers", though that was mid-90's with Peter Weller. It was pretty B-movies, so it looked 80s-ish. I remember they had to smoke red cigarettes in a radiation field (and how that makes sense, I have no idea) which is why I thought of this with the limited description. They were on an alien planet, with two obvious isdes, fighting a sort of civil war. One side used little burrowing robots to kill their opponents but were just as lethal to them, and they evolved. Any luck with this description?

Comment: "Screamers" does not fit the bill as the action took place on Mars and the cigarettes they smoked was to thwart the radiation given off by the resources they mined there. and there was no civilization involved only a few soldiers (less then 10 on either side) that were left there after a fight between the corporations and the miners.

Comment: @user you seriously put out more information than the original question had. It never mentioned any planet, and cigarettes are considered a drug (well, nicotine), and how would you not know if I were right or not?

Comment: screamers was at least a B+ or A- movie.

Answer (score 2):

Woo, sound like Outland with Sean Connery.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outland_(film)

Comment: The Outland mystery, and crime, was about how the mining colony manager explored and encouraged the use of drugs to extend the abilities of the mining colonists. It had nothing to do with radiation protection.

Comment: If it is Outland, take a look at [this answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/12008/help-me-to-find-the-title-of-this-movie/12009#12009).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is your film, but your description reminded me of "Fallout", a PC-game (you probably know it).

Fallout got his influence from a film called [A boy and his dog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Boy_and_His_Dog) from 1975.

Haven't seen it myself, but maybe this is what youre looking for?

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't it. I'm quite sure it's set in space or in a future where space travel is common.

Comment: Ok, sry for that. There are many postapocalyptic movies with drugs (Judge Dredd, Dredd, Dune, Soilent Green, ...) so I just mix em together... good look though!

Comment: I loved Fallout. Is that movie any good?

Comment: A Boy And His Dog was definately... wierd. It's got Don Johnson pretty young, and its a bit loopy at times. Haven't seen it in ages, but you might find it on Netflix. The last lines are kinda screwball, and the author hated them, so don't take that part too seriously. Worth it, and it's like #79 on Sci-Fi films, especially since it wasn't commercially successful.

Answer (score 0):

It is [*Screamers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screamers_(1995_film)). In the film, they smoke some cigars. The Boy they find is a robot who tries to kill them. Their mission is to make a peace treaty, but it doesn't turn out how they thought. Very intense movie. Well, it was when I watched it a long time ago.

Comment: Hi and welcome :) Try to add a link to your title ;)

Comment: This made me think of the Thals who lived around the City of the Daleks, the planet is so irradiated they take drugs to survive

Answer (score 0):

The movie you were looking for is *Hardware* (1990).

From [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0099740/):

> The head of a cyborg reactivates, rebuilds itself, and goes on a violent rampage in a space marine's girlfriend's apartment.

Comment: Can you explain why you think this is the right answer?

Answer (score 0):

It’s Screamers. They are mining and in a kind of civil war. They refer to a group mining Berynium on Triton 4. The also refer to the red cigarettes in at least two scenes. Here is an excerpt:

> The funny thing is, I can't remember what she looked like.
>
> Liar.
>
> Automated voice over loud speaker:
>
> Attention, all personnel.
>
> Warning, radiation alert, please light your reds.
>
> Oh, I left mine in the office, you got one?